# Is many-body Hamiltonian valid in strong-correlated system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, coulombs-law

Condensed-matter textbook often states that there is a many-body Hamiltonian
$$ H= \sum_i \frac{ p_i^2}{2m_i} + \sum_{i>j} V_{ij} \tag{1} $$
where $V_{ij} = Z_i Z_j/r_{ij}$.

This Hamiltonian encodes almost all the information  (except relativistic correction, gravity, etc) of condensed matter physics including strongly-correlated system. It is impractical and not insightful to compute properties of (1).  Several effective theories are then introduced.

My question is, Coulomb law is derived from the tree-diagram in QED, which is perturbative. Does strong correlation effect break the perturbative derivation of Coulomb law, thus invalid Hamiltonian (1)? If strong correlation does not break Hamiltonian (1), how to derive (1) from QED?

Comment: I didn't realized the Coulomb law was a derived approximation.  So this isn't as fundamental as it gets for quantum chemistry?

Comment: It is a derived property in QED, e.g. Peksin p125